# Why can't I view the plan for view creation...?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

```
mysql> EXPLAIN EXTENDED
    create algorithm =temptable view fisgen_temptable(inter,phone)
    as select intercom1,phone from fisgen where fid='f105';
```

I am getting an error like this:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'create
>   algorithm =temptable view fisgen_temptable(inter,phone)
>   as select interc' at line 2

Answer (score 2):

`EXPLAIN` shows an execution plan for `SELECT` queries. In [version 5.6](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html), it was extended to include plans for `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `REPLACE` statements.

No version of MySQL (not even the still in development, 5.7) has `EXPLAIN` for `CREATE TABLE` or `CREATE VIEW`.

You can of course run the explain for the select (that defines the view):

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED
    select intercom1,phone from fisgen where fid='f105';
```

or as @jynus suggested (thank you), the more useful:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED
    select * from fisgen_temptable;
```

Comment: For @Lakshmi Also, `EXPLAIN CREATE VIEW` in current versions of MySQL would make no sense, as there are no materialized tables- query is not executed at creation time. You can, however, `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM fisgen_temptable`.

Comment: @jynus, thnx, I've added you suggestion in the answer. I think it's more useful.